# What is the difference between "Save" and "Done" in Camera Raw?

Tags: adobe-indesign, image-processing, adobe-bridge, raw-format

I processed some JPGs in Camera Raw and clicked the `Done` button. The changes seem to have been saved, as I can see in the thumbnail in Adobe Bridge.

Then I have placed the image in an InDesign file, but there the changes don't seem to have been saved. Do I have to choose the save button instead in Camera Raw to get the changes saved properly?

Comment: What format are you placing the images in? Are you placing CR files in Indesign or not sure?

Comment: Sorry i didn´t see your answer until now. Anyhow the files I placed in indesign are jpegs. But the problem is solved. I did open all the files in adobe bridge and did a save as which solved the problem. As I understand it when you choose done it doesnt change the image per se.

Answer (score 1):

**Done** stores changes in the sidecar file (or metadata) but does not directly apply them to the image. (So you can come back later and further adjust before actually applying anything.)

**Save** applies the changes to the image.

The same is generally true for *any* Adobe dialog window with both a "done" and "save" button.

(Small tip.. you should *never* save a jpg as a jpg.)